# Two homogeneous polynomial of the same degree define the same projective hypersurface if and only if they are proportional

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Fix $n, m\ge0$ and let $A=\mathbb{K}[T_0,...,T_n]$ and $F,G \in A$ two homogeneous, nonzero, polynomial of the same degree $m$. Show that $$V(F)=V(G) \qquad iff \quad\exists \lambda \neq 0 \quad\text{such that}\quad G=\lambda F$$

Note that for any $F \in A$, $V(F)$ is the closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (with Zariski topology) defined as the zero set of $F$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, e.g $V(F)=\{(x_0:\cdots:x_n) \in \mathbb{P}^n \,:\, F(x_0,...,x_n)=0\}$ and called projective hypersurface defined by $F$.

---

Trivially if $G=\lambda F$ for some $\lambda\neq 0$ then $V(F)=V(G)$.

On the other side, let $F,G \in A$ homogeneous of the same degree $m$ such that $V(F)=V(G)$. By Nullstellensatz theorem this means that $\sqrt{(F)}=\sqrt{(G)}$ and so some power of $F$ divides G and conversely some power of $G$ divides $F$. Is there a way from this to conclude that $F$ and $G$ are proportional? Probably it's such a simple proof but I can't find now any good attempt.

I'm just trying to understand the Veronese embedding has declared [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=tyK4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=since%20polynomials%20define%20the%20same%20hypersurface%20if%20and%20only%20if&source=bl&ots=KHdpqhFPq6&sig=49pRShZJWSDZJB_7foZY9du7Frw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp7PTJoJ7YAhVJVBQKHc1KDQ0Q6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=since%20polynomials%20define%20the%20same%20hypersurface%20if%20and%20only%20if&f=false).

Comment: This is probably not true. For example I can fix $n=1, \, m=3$ and consider $F={T_0}^2T_1$, $G=T_0{T_1}^2$. They define the same variety $V(F)=V(G)=\{(0:1),(1:0)\}$, but they are not proportional.

Comment: It is true when you add the assumption that your polynomials are square-free.